# How can I procedurally modify this texture to make it look right?

Tags: texturing, uv, transparency

I have a texture extracted from an online source.  It's the face texture for a human character, with hair and beard included.  For clarity's sake, the hair portion is in the lower right, the beard portion is in the upper left, and the upper right portion is for hair planes.  This image is a PNG, and so a lot of the white space you see is actually transparency.  I'm using this texture, and the model to which it belongs, in Blender.

I can get the transparency for this character to work, but the basic color is off.  This character should have dark brown hair, but as you can see in the image, it is initially colored blue and green.  I can usually fiddle with it enough for it to approximate the correct hair color, but I've got a lot of these type of files and I'm hoping there is some procedural fix that I could apply to every texture I extract so I won't have to make my best guess.  I've tried fiddling with image adjustments in Photoshop, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Is there a single-click, or few-clicks, solution that would translate the colors in this texture into the correct colors?

[image: Sample Texture File]

Comment: The hair looks like a normal map

Comment: I agree, but there are separate normal maps, and this seems to be the only base texture map.

Comment: I think the way the color varies it'd be hard to apply one transformation to it to get the result you want.

Comment: What do the areas to be corrected have in common? Are they all the same color-range, in the same place, or whatever?

Comment: That's partly what I'm trying to figure out.  All the figures I get from this source have the same problem; the hair sections are discolored.  All other body parts are textured just fine, in both the diffuse and normal texture maps.  It's just the hair sections that are discolored.